# Finding constant multiple of parallel vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Given two n-dimensional vectors that are parallel, is there any way to computationally find k such that

$$\vec{v}_{1} = k\vec{v}_2$$

without prodding into the components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\vec{v}_2 \ne \vec{0},\;$ you use the dot product and get
$$\vec{v}_{1} \cdot \vec{v}_2 = k\vec{v}_2 \cdot \vec{v}_2
\Longrightarrow
k = \frac{\vec{v}_{1} \cdot \vec{v}_2} {\vec{v}_{2} \cdot \vec{v}_2}
$$